# Why doesn't this code replace my string?

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

Ok.. this has been asked here 10 times and its usually the immutable issue.
My code looks like this:

```
For i = 0 To filterlist.Length - 1
    Dim s = filterlist(i)
    If s.Length > 2 Then
        Dim ts = xmlString.Replace(s, "<temps>" + s + "</temps>")
        xmlString = ts
    End If
Next
```

filterlist is an array(n) of strings.
In case anyone wants to know what I'm replacing.. its XML that has bad formatting and it looks like this:

```
     <property>g_defaultPBSConversionParams<Bool>false</Bool></property>
     <property>g_metallicConversions<Vector4>0.025 0.355 1.373 2.913</Vector4></property>
     <property>g_glossConversions<Vector4>0.185 0.478 0.588 0.735</Vector4></property>
     <property>g_albedoConversions<Vector4>0.05 0.65 0.513 0.5</Vector4></property>
     <property>normalMap
<Texture>vehicles/american/tracks/T54_E2_track_NM.dds</Texture></property>
     <property>diffuseMap
<Texture>vehicles/american/tracks/T54_E2_track.dds</Texture></property>
     <property>specularMap
<Texture>vehicles/american/tracks/T54_E2_track_SM.dds</Texture></property>
     <property>alphaReference<Int>16</Int></property>
     <property>alphaTestEnable<Bool>true</Bool></property>
```

You can see that there is a string value after the property tag that is bad XML formatting. I can't display it correctly until I wrap these extra entries. The extra junk will not let the XmlTextWriter do its job and make it all pretty for me.

Comment: If you add the language tag, you may get faster assistance with this.

Comment: Is your question about your code not working, or are you looking for pointers how to code a solution?

Comment: Im trying to figure out why it will not replace the string sections. I have done this 100s of times exactly like this and now.. its broke. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the xml string>

Answer (score 0):

I not so smart.. After staring at this for an hour..(Obviously too long) I finally figure out there is an extra white character at the start of every string my filterlist array